# Vector: How to filter out segments of decreasing values

Tags: r, vector, filter, filtering

Let's say there is a vector `sim` that contains the following sequence of numbers:

```
1
2
4
7
5
3
2.5
4
6
```

How can I filter out all the segments of decreasing values in order to achieve `sim` with only increasing values? The expected result:

```
1
2
4
7
2.5
4
6
```

Comment: In your result, 7 to 2.5 doesn't look like an increasing value. Do you just want `1 2 4 7`? Or do you want to filter it to get all stretches of increasing values that are length 2 or greater?

Comment: based on your requirements should `sim` be `c(1,2,4,7,4,6)` at the end, or am I misunderstanding your post?

Comment: If `2.5` is a typo then `sim[c(TRUE,diff(sim)>0)]`.  If the condition is `>-1` , `sim[c(TRUE,diff(sim)>-1)]`

Comment: @Andrew Taylor: I want to cut out segments with decreasing values, in this case: 5 and 3. The issue is that I want to keep 7 and 2.5 as the end and beginning of increasing segments, respectively.

Comment: @David Robinson: yes, correct, I want to get all stretches of increasing values that are length 2 or greater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on @akrun's suggestion:

```
dif <- diff(sim) > 0
sim[ c(dif[1], dif) | c(dif, dif[length(dif)]) ]
[1] 1.0 2.0 4.0 7.0 2.5 4.0 6.0
```

Comment: Will it work if the number of stretches of increasing values is greater than 2?

Comment: If I understand your question correcly, then yes it will. No limit to the number of stretches, just try adding or removing elements of sim.